# Delphi Firemonkey 3D: How can I change the origin from which a 3D object rotates?

Tags: delphi, 3d, rotation, firemonkey

The cube rotates when the user holds down the LMB and moves the mouse.I am using a dummy as a kind of "anchor", so that the camera stays in the same place, but the object rotates, so all sides can be seen by rotating the object (which is a cube). The problem is that after rotating the object, its x and y remain constant, so that the same motion causes a different effect from the camera's perspective. e.g. If I rotate 180 degrees up(y), the x axis' rotation is mirrored, in that moving the mouse left rotates in th opposite direction as it would before the 180 degree rotation

Here is my code:

Form Create:

```
procedure TForm2.Form3DCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Xf := 0;
Yf := 0;
Xi := 0;
Yi := 0;
Xd := 0;
Yd := 0;
end;
```

Start Button:

```
procedure TForm2.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);    
begin
layerStart.Visible := False;
Controller := TController.create(Form2,10);
Camera1 := TCamera.Create(Controller.getAnchor);
Camera1.Parent := Controller.getAnchor;
Anchor := Controller.getAnchor;
Timer1.Enabled := True;

end;
```

Creation of Object and 'Anchor':

```
Type
 tController = class
   private
     cubeArray : Array[1..10,1..10,1..10]  of TCube;
     fCubeCount, fHalf : integer;
     fForm : TForm3D;
     bigCube : tDummy;
   public
    constructor create(Form : TForm3D; cubeCount :integer);
    function getAnchor : tDummy;

 end;

implementation

{ tController }

constructor tController.create(Form: TForm3D; cubeCount: integer); //cubeCount Max 10, min 1
var
  x, y, z : Integer;
begin
fCubeCount := cubeCount;
fForm := Form;
fHalf := cubeCount div 2;
bigCube := TDummy.Create(Form);
With bigCube do
         begin
           Visible := True;
           Position.X := 0;
           Position.Y := 0;
           Position.Z := 0;
           Parent := Form;
         end;

for x := 1 to fCubeCount do
 begin
  for y := 1 to fCubeCount do
   begin
    for z := 1 to fCubeCount do
     begin
       CubeArray[x,y,z] := TCube.Create(bigCube);
        With CubeArray[x,y,z] do
         begin
           Visible := True;
           Width := 0.5;
           Height := 0.5;
           Depth := 0.5;
           Position.X := x - 0.5 - fHalf;
           Position.Y := y - 0.5 - fHalf;
           Position.Z := z - 0.5 - fHalf;
           Parent := bigCube;
         end;
        end;
    end;
   end;

 end;

function tController.getAnchor: TDummy;
begin
result := bigCube;
end;



end.
```

Timer:

```
procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

// X on Form to Left = 60; X on form to right = 1280
  while GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) = -32768  do
   begin
    Xi := Screen.MousePos.X;
    Yi := Screen.MousePos.Y;
    Sleep(1);
    Xf := Screen.MousePos.X;
    Yf := Screen.MousePos.Y;

    Xd := (Xi-Xf);
    Yd := (Yi-Yf)*-1;// *-1 for compliance with Cartesian plane logic

    Xd := (Xd / 1220)*360*10; //COnverting from X units to degrees, *10 for more rotation per amount moved by mouse
    Yd := (Yd / 1220)*360*10;


Anchor.RotationAngle.Y := Anchor.RotationAngle.Y + Xd;
Anchor.RotationAngle.X := Anchor.RotationAngle.X + Yd;
Application.ProcessMessages;

   end;


   end;
```

The object I want to rotate is the cube which is made up of all the smaller cubes. As far as I know, this issue stems from the fact the the anchor remains the same relative to the cube after rotation i.e. the origin of rotation moves with the object which rotates. 
How would I fix this?

Comment: `Sleep()` and `Application.ProcessMessages` inside an `OnTimer` event is a big nono.

Comment: Please read the descriptions that pop up for tags as you select them. The `anchor` tag here specifically refers to anchors in HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind (anchors). What should I do intead of using sleep and Application.ProcessMessages?

Comment: You need to save last mouse pos plus a boolean if last pos was valid. When a new valid pos arrives, make your transformation and update the anchor properties plus save this pos as last pos. If the mouse button is up, invalidate last pos. I'm not sure that the timer is the right place to handle the animation. You will have to experiment. See this demo that does some animation in the application.OnIdle event, [`FMX ImageSpin`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/FMX.ImageSpin_Sample).

Comment: Note, don't loop your GetAsyncKeyState(). Just run the logic once per timer interval.